# Is there an API to cancel/delay a server reboot after installing automatic updates at night?

Tags: java, windows, updates

Our business software (written in java) try to update itself during the night (like windows does). The more systems we have out there the often it happens that windows reboots itself (after installing its updates) and just kill our update-process leaving it in critical state.
Because of other events like long working customers, daily automatic routines (which sometimes needs hours of time to complete), backups, etc. the time frame for installing our updates sometimes moves to midnight and collide with said windows reboots. This is bad.

Is there an API, tool or any other control mechanism to either delay the reboot until we're finished with our updates or to check if there will happen such a reboot in the near future. For the latter it would be enough if I can check if windows is going to install updates this night so that I can postpone our own updates to the next day.

Edit: Our Software is installed on our customers server. So that we usually have Windows Server systems under the hood.

Comment: see https://www.extremetech.com/computing/243620-stop-windows-10-automatically-rebooting-updates

Comment: Thanks. But this manually needs to be done per every installed system which isn't an adequate solution. I try to "fix" this per software so that we do not need to call all our customers (or their IT-Specialists) to get this done.